# controller argument deserializes DateTime to UTC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is behavior just the opposite of what was expected.

For C# DateTime type, I was expecting with no trailing "Z" in the json string it will be considered as local time zone value.

Here is the controller [HttpPut]

```
 public IHttpActionResult UpdateSomeInfo(int someId, [FromBody] ClassWithDateTime obj)
```

The input coming in as dateTime format looks as below:

```
 "start":"9/24/2020 12:55:00PM"
```

When I debug, I notice the converted property value of DateTime type contains Kind as utc... which throws  me out of bus.... why??  Shouldn't this be deserialized as local time with kind as unspecified or local??

Comment: Because you receive the `ClassWithDateTime` instance via JSON that's why a simple 
 `TypeConverter` could be enough. Otherwise you would need to consider to implement a custom model binder to parse it in the desired local time.

Comment: Wouldn't the time format without 'Z' mean local time in that ISO standard?  I am not convinced in setting Kind as UTC when the time format doesn't contain 'Z'.